# What is the difference between 10% and $\frac{1}{10}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics, descriptive-statistics

In a national competition , ech school had to choose 10% of students who participated in the competition .

So my question is , why they didn't asked for $\frac{1}{10}$ of students who participated ?

For example for 200 students we have to choose 20 students ! For 120 we have to choose 12 . But for 20 we have to choose 2 or 10 because if we choose 2 we are doing the $\frac{1}{10}$ case ! So if number of students is small than 100 we have to choose in all cases 10 students ???

Comment: $10\%$ is the same as $\frac1{10}$, at least when talking about parts of a whole ($10\%$ of students, $\frac1{10}$ of the pages in a book, $10\%$ off a price, and so on).

Comment: `But for 20 we have to choose 2 or 10 because if we choose 2 we are doing the 1/10 case` - why do you think you would need to pick 10 instead of 2?

Comment: Because when they want 10 of 100 that means they want 10 students from every school

Comment: @user233658 but they are asking for *ten percent*, not for *ten*

Comment: "10 out of 100" implies you have to have 100 students to choose 10. You can't choose 10 students out of 20. The fact that you choose _any_ students out of 20 is because we treat "10 out of 100" as $1/10$. In reality we also allow some rounding, for example a school with 98 students will probably choose 10 students, not 9.

Answer (score 4):

I define $\%=\frac{1}{100}$ so

$$10\%=10\cdot\frac{1}{100}=\frac{1}{10}.$$

Comment: Let's be clear about your first line to clear all confusion.  If $A$ is any number, you define "$A \%$" to be $A \cdot \frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: Yes... absolutely.

Comment: ...I consider % an element of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

To take $10\%$ of a quantity $X$, you multiply $X$ by $\frac{1}{10}$. So, for example, $10\%$ of $20$ is $\frac{1}{10}\cdot 20 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

If a school has to send ${1\over10}$ of its  students then strictly speaking that school cannot take part if its total number of students is not divisible by $10$. If the school has to send $10\%$ of its students then everyone accepts that the resulting number is rounded to the nearest integer.